# Use method define in node.js module exports

Tags: node.js, methods, module, export

I have a node.js module that has `foo` and `bar`. Is there a way for me to call `foo` inside of `bar` like:

```
module.exports = {
    foo: function(a, b, c) {

    },

    bar: function(a, b, c) {
        foo(); //returns 'foo is not defined'
    }
}
```

As is, `foo` returns undefined... can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. Just use `this`.

```
module.exports = {
    foo: function(a, b, c) {

    },

    bar: function(a, b, c) {
        this.foo();
    }
}
```

I recommend reading [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) on working with objects.

Answer (score 1):

@victorkohl's answer will work. Alternatively, you can also use closure to avoid invoking `this`:

```
function foo (a, b, c) {
}

function bar (a, b, c) {
    foo();
}

module.exports = {
    foo: foo,
    bar: bar
};
```

Answer (score 1):

And just for the fun of it, this works too:

```
    foo(); //returns 'foo is not defined'
```

with

```
    module.exports.foo();
```

(I recommend the self contained version from @victorkohl.)